# Bootstrap dropdown menu with image broke alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I am using this bootstrap templete https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/BizPage/, the problem is that I need a image in the dropdown menu but it broke menu alignment, somebody can help?

The full code was too large to add here so I uploaded to this FIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/Lgdohawm/
please on js fiddle editor layout choose 
 `Columns Bottom results` because It will show the full width result page

Part of menu - html only

```html
    <header id="header" style="background-color:black">
                 <nav id="nav-menu-container">
                    <ul class="nav-menu">
                      <li class="menu-active"><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
             <!-- menu with image -->
                      <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="" class="sf-with-ul"><img class="rounded-circle" width="45" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50">&nbsp;@user</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Drop Down 4</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Drop Down 5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
              <!-- menu with image -->
                      <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
             <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </header>
```

menu code is between html comments tag `<!-- menu with image -->`

Comment: Have you tried to play with image size? For example, now it's `45px` but `li`s height is `33px`. Also can you possibly provide more details on what you tried so far?

Comment: yeah it was the `float: left` that was causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using

```
float: left
```

for the menu items?

You can simply use

```
.nav-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

instead.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqx1mt5c/)